# How to convert KG into LBS using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on XSLT, I have huge xml on which I need to perform rename , move and delete operation. Most of the transformation is done now I want to convert the Kilo Gram into LBS.

Let say :

```
<main>
<part>
<weight>1</weight>
<weightunits></weightunits>
</part>
</main>
```

This could be any part of xml. 
I want to convert the value of `<weight>` which could be in KG into LBS and put inside the `<weightunits>`. First up all is it possible and if yes how can i do that

Comment: What do you mean by  "*could be in KG*"? The `weightunits`element in the given example is empty; do you want to assume it's kilograms when it's empty? Are all  `weightunits`elements in the input empty?

Comment: @michael.hor257k The `<weight>` is 1 KG and I want the result in `<weightunits>`

Comment: @michael.hor257k Output would be like `<weight>1</weight>` and `<weightunits>2.20462</weightunits>`

Comment: @michael.hor257k The value of `<weight>` is not fixed it could be any integer

Comment: Such output makes no sense; clearly, the `weight` element is designed to hold the numeric value and the `weightunits` is supposed to have the name of the unit.

Comment: @michael.hor257k It is like whatever the value is there in `<weight>` needs to be convert into LBS and put that value in `<weightunits>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to have something like:

```
<xsl:template match="weight">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select=". div 0.45359237"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="weightunits">
    <weightunits>lb</weightunits>
</xsl:template>
```

This is assuming **all** your weights are given in kilograms.

---

### Added:

> It is like whatever the value is there in `<weight>` needs to be
>   convert into LBS and put that value in `<weightunits>`

I am convinced you are making a mistake here because - as I said in the comments - the `weightunits` element is supposed to hold the **name** of the unit whose numerical **value** is stored in `weight`.

But if you insist, then all you need to do is:

```
<xsl:template match="weightunits">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="../weight div 0.45359237"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Its worked. thanks. Only difficulty is with the position I want to move the value to `<weightunits>` while i try that it is taking the old value on weight that is 1

Comment: @AnandDeshmukh See the addition to my answer.